# Why isn't the complete array pushed to the UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextview, uistoryboardsegue

Here is my code:

```
-(void)printHistory:(NSArray*)songPrintList {
    for(int t=0; t<[songPrintList count]; t++) {
        [sonHistory setText:[[songPrintList objectAtIndex:t]capitalizedString]];
        NSLog(@"%d %@", t, [songPrintList objectAtIndex:t]);
    }
}
```

This method is called on viewDidLoad.
The NSLoad logs the whole array to the console but the UITextView, songHistory, just gets the last string from the array.

I should add that this is a modal view and the array comes from the "parent" view via segue.

Comment: Ok this shows how much of a stackoverflow noob I am! Sorry for the code thingie. Luckily it isn't that much of code. I guess someone nice will edit it for me.

Comment: That's because you always overwrite the old text instead of appending the new string to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)printHistory:(NSArray*)songPrintList {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
    for(int t=0; t<[songPrintList count]; t++) {
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:[[songPrintList objectAtIndex:t]capitalizedString]];
        NSLog(@"%d %@", t, [songPrintList objectAtIndex:t]);
    }
    [sonHistory setText:str];
}
```